# npm package resolution : why does it go to the server?

Tags: node.js, npm

If we install a package, its dependencies graph is resolved, and dependencies are downloaded once. Here, for instance, colors is not downloaded twice.

[image]

However, the http 304 suggests that a round trip was made to the server, and I dont understand why we would need that, as we have all the dependencies information in the packages.json.

I know the whole thing can be cached in `npm config get cache` to save trafic but is there more subtle reason, like version locking etc, to have this resolution be handled by an indirect mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the registry is necessary. The package can be modified or deleted. Package may have different versions, which may not be available.

200 response means that new registry has been downloaded. 304 means not modified. Also this link is the registry not the package itself. So it is just metadata.

Comment: necessary for modification : between the 1st call and the second one ?

Comment: @nicolas All I can say there is no predetermined way to know when the change happens. You have to check it everytime you use it. Besides 304 code means that last response cached is still valid.